# Get variable *value* instead of variable itself

Tags: javascript, variables

Look at this code:

```
<button id="button">Test</button>
<button id="button2">Test</button>

<script>

  button = document.getElementById("button");
  button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

  var x = 5;

  button.onclick = function() {
    alert(x);
  }

  var x = 10;

  button2.onclick = function() {
    alert(x);
  }


</script>
```

When I click on both of the buttons, I get `10` as result. But I wanted to get `5` as result for the first button. I.e, I didn't want to set the alert parameter to the variable, but rather the actual value *of* the variable. Is it possible to do that in JavaScript?

Comment: `(function (x) { button.onclick = …; })(x)`

Comment: What does this mean: `I didn't want to set the alert parameter to the variable, but rather the actual value of the variable. Is it possible to do that in JavaScript?`? Does it mean you want 5 for the first button and 10 for the second or something else?

Comment: "Does it mean you want 5 for the first button and 10 for the second?". Yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JavaScript has function scope for variables. If you want to use the same variable twice but it should not be the same reference, you need to put the code in different scopes (functions). So you could do this:

```
button = document.getElementById("button");
button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

(function() {
    var x = 5;

    button.onclick = function() {
        alert(x);
    }
})();

(function() {
    var x = 10;

    button2.onclick = function() {
        alert(x);
    }
})();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q91uhvw3/

Or if you do not want to do that, you can force evaluation of `x` at the time of creating the `onclick` handler for the first button like so:

```
button = document.getElementById("button");
button2 = document.getElementById("button2");


var x = 5;

(function(xRightNow) {
    button.onclick = function() {
        alert(xRightNow);
    }
})(x);

var x = 10;

button2.onclick = function() {
    alert(x);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q91uhvw3/2/

Comment: You are one of few that actually have understood my question.

Comment: @gustavwiz You can indeed use local variables but what I was demonstrating is simply by passing in `x` to a parameter of the inner function, you have created a new variable -- the value of `x` gets assigned to `xRightNow` and "right now" is in the context of code evaluation. Please accept the answer if it answers your question (click the green checkmark next to it). Your variations are not technically different -- just slightly different syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if this all single line code then you're overwriting `x`.

If you wanted them to have different results per function than you could write the values *local* to the function.

```
  button.onclick = function() {
    var x = 5;// now local to the function
    alert(x);
  }


  button2.onclick = function() {
    var x = 10;// now local to the function
    alert(x);
  }
```

Your code is doing something like this:

1. declare x as 5,

   set the callback for the first button to alert x

   change x to 10

   set the callback for the second button to alert x

   (button clicked) ---> alerts the current value of x which was last changed to 10

**The problem** is that your function didn't save the value of `x` when it was 5. You're just grabbing the variable `x`whenever it is called, so it grabs whatever the current value is.

What mine does is:

1. set the callback for the first button to a function

   that function sets a local variable called x to equal 5

   that function will alert the local variable whos value was set to 5

   (button clicked) ---> alerts the current value of x, which was declared locally as 5

Comment: The first 'x' is being overwritten, this is due to hoisting. the answer above explains that (kind of) by putting variables into their own scopes they are then not overwritten when they are declared again.

Read up on 'hoisting' - as code is executed in a specific order.

Comment: @NewZeroRiot My answer explains that as well. And it doesn't require the confusing to begginers anonymous function calling. That literally has no added benefit to his answer.

Comment: Only confusing if that isn't what the question is about -- the question is vague enough at the end to not be clear. I assumed it was actually asking about how scope worked.

Comment: This answer did not help me. You have used the numbers 5 and 10 inside the event function, but I only have variables there. So that doesn't work.